# Poor signal for windows desktop wireless adapter. Mac and mobile phone have full signal

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

Having a strange issue at the moment. The location that I'm at, I have three devices. AN android phone, a mac laptop, and a windows 10 desktop. The first two have full bars and the internet is pulling down ~40megs. However, the desktop connection barely has any signal, and is nigh unusable. I've attempted multiple remedies, including resetting the wireless adapter, but with no success. This is the only time that this system has had wireless issues since I've owned it, and at this point I'm open to any advice that wouldn't involve replacing the motherboard that the wireless adapter is housed on, as a wired connection isn't available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update the driver on the wireless card. Get a USB wireless card as an alternative. Get a USB wired Ethernet card as an alternative.

Comment: @john sadly already tried the drivers bit. Wired wont help as there's no wired options for internet. So looks like wireless is the way to go and hope that works. Seems strange how the other devices work fine though

Comment: Yes, an alternative Wireless adapter is probably the way to go.